# Size of ViewSite in Eclipse RCP

Tags: eclipse-rcp

Is there a way to determine the size (height and width) of a view site (IViewSite) in eclipse rcp? I try to optimize the appearance of view parts and therefore need these sizes.

Comment: You should use [Layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm) everywhere so that the parts are layed out automatically.

Comment: Take a look at the extension point named "org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions". It allows you to organize the layout of the views in your perspective.